# How to turn off “macOS MDM Enrollment”

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, filevault, mdm

I have a MacBook Pro that I bought on eBay. There’s an annoying message that pops up every few minutes “macOS MDM Enrollment” is the title. I’ve tried several different methods posted on this site to remove it. I’ve been in Recovery Mode more times than I can count. I’ve turned off FileVault, removed all of the pertinent files from LaunchAgent and LaunchDaemon,unmounted and mounted my volume, etc. Nothing has been effective. I’m running Monterey v12.2.1 on an Intel 2019 MacBook Pro. Can anyone suggest something new?

Comment: Have you erased the disk and installed a clean copy of macOS?

Comment: There is nothing on the computer that will bypass this, this machine is enrolled in an MDM solution. Does the computer say who it belongs to?

Comment: Gilby: I haven’t done that because there’s a lot of premium software on it that I’d rather not lose. There are several methods posted that have worked for others, just not me.

Comment: Nothing that was on the computer when you bought it belongs to you. First time there's an update or an OS update, or sometimes seemingly at random, you'll be asked to enter the original owner's Apple ID credentials… which you don't have. You're going to have to face up to the fact that what you most probably have is a stolen computer, or at best one they forgot to unenrol. The MDM can only be unlocked by the original owner.

Answer (score 4):

There are no "methods" you can try locally to remove it from the MDM it is enrolled in.

Contact the company that claims ownership of the device and find out the actual status.  They may want it back.